# pop() always returns the same on an int set{}?

Tags: python, string, integer, set

In the first set (a string set), the `pop()` method will work perfectly, but with the second (an int set) it only pops the "first" position/index in the set, all the time. Not a random one.

```
Set_with_string_data = {"Brunno", "Silva", "Pereira"}
Set_with_string_data.pop()
print(Set_with_string_data)
```

Outputs each time something different:

```
{"Brunno", "Silva"}
{"Silva", "Pereira"}
{"Pereira", "Brunno"}
```

But this:

```
Set_with_integer_data = {1, 2, 3, 4}
Set_with_integer_data.pop()
print(Set_with_integer_data)
```

always outputs:

```
{2, 3, 4}
{2, 3, 4}
{2, 3, 4}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you said is not true. it relates to the hash values of the list elements and particular interprtor.
try this and you most likely still see 1 pop-ed

```
Set_with_intenger_data = {4, 3, 2, 1}
Set_with_intenger_data.pop()
print(Set_with_intenger_data)
```

Comment: Okay, I get it. But shouldn't that always take away a new random element?

Comment: as said this relates to the internal data structure of set (which relies on the hash() values of the elements). It is never random and don't count on its behavior. Instead, use a real random generator and select.

Comment: ooh. Ok. Now I get it. Thank you!